# JEE App with JMX

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jmx

I am developing an application in JEE

I work under eclipse and with Tomcat as application server.

I introduce the notions of Java Management Extensions (JMX).

Search on this API I find that is used to collect information from the networks on machines or servers.

I give you an overview of the purpose of my project. It is an application JEE connect with a web part (in jsp and servlet)
 of a bank .

But I want to know how to use jmx in my App

Please I need help

thank you in advance

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow.
Please try to explain what kind of result you wanna achieve using JMX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would honestly go through some of Oracles extensive documentation over using JMX. Since it is a very specific library, they will have the best documentation for you to reference to get you jump started.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jmx/examples.html

Good luck!